# How do I run two queries in my JSP file. Following is my code

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I want to execute the following code that includes two SQL Queries to be executed within. I keep getting SQL Exception. Code goes here. Thank you in advance.

```
     <table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>FileName</th>
            <th>Ip</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Download</th>
        </tr>
        <%

            Connection con = DbConnector.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pstm = null;
            String sql = "select * from transaction where     status='Success'";
            pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {%>
        <tr>
            <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
            <% 
            PreparedStatement pstm1 = null;
            String sql2 = "select * from mykeys where FileID = '"+ rs.getString(7).toString() +"'";
            pstm1 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
            ResultSet rs1 = pstm1.executeQuery();

                                                      if(rs1.getString(2).toString() != null &&      rs1.getString(3).toString() != null){%>
            <td><a href="FileDownload?ip=    <%=rs.getString(4)%>&filename=<%=rs.getString(2)%>">Download</a></td>
            <%}else{%>
            <td>Cannot Download</td>
            <%}%>
       </tr>

        <%}%>
</table>
```

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
 org.apache.jsp.report_jsp._jspService(report_jsp.java:200)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)

Comment: this is what JSP SQL is for , give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is at below line. Most probably by mistake you forget to call `rs1.next()` before getting the data.

```
ResultSet rs1 = pstm1.executeQuery();
if(rs1.getString(2).toString() != null &&  rs1.getString(3).toString() != null)
```

It should be

```
ResultSet rs1 = pstm1.executeQuery();
if(rs1.next() && rs1.getString(2).toString() != null && rs1.getString(3).toString() != null)
```

Please have a look at [JDBC Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) where you will learn the basics of the JDBC API.

---

Note:

- Try to avoid Scriplet in JSP rather use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) that is more easy to use and less error prone.
- Use [JSTL SQL Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL7.html) for direct database access in JSP

Find sample code here on [JSP JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)